# BottomBar fragments in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can I add fragments for each tab in BottomBar in Android studio please a good example like list view or grid view for each tab..thanks

Comment: visit this : http://androidcodeblogspot.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-fragment-tab-example-bottom.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement SetOnTabSelectListerner.

```
bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

                Fragment fragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass = null;

                switch (tabId) {
                    case R.id.tab_one:
                        fragmentClass = TabOneFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_two:
                        fragmentClass = TabTwoFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_three:
                        fragmentClass = TabThreeFragment.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_four:
                        fragmentClass = TabFourFragment.class;
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

main_activity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements communicator{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void respond(int i) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentB f2= (FragmentB)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changedata(i);
    }
}

main_activity.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BBFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample.MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample.FragmentA"
        />
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample.FragmentB"
        />
</android.widget.LinearLayout>










fragmentA.java

package com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    ListView list;
    communicator comm;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm= (communicator) getActivity();
        list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayAdapter ad=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.listval,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(ad);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
           }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView txt=(TextView)view;
        String str=txt.getText().toString();
        comm.respond(position);
    }
}






























fragmentA.xml

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample.FragmentA"
    android:background="#FFBB00">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"/>
</FrameLayout>







fragmentB.java
package com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
TextView txt;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        txt=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textv);
    }
    public void changedata(int i)
    {
        Resources res=getResources();
        String[] des=res.getStringArray(R.array.desciptions);
       // String str=Integer.toString(i);
        txt.setText(des[i]);
       // txt.setText(str);    }}
fragmentB.xml

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentexample.FragmentB"
    android:background="#99CC00"
    >
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textv"/>
</FrameLayout>



strings.xml

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyFragmentExample</string>
    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string-array name="listval">
        <item>fragments</item>
        <item>Activities</item>
        <item>Services</item>
        <item>Content Providers</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="desciptions">
        <item>A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).</item>
        <item>Activities are one of the fundamental building blocks of apps on the Android platform. They serve as the entry point for a user's interaction with an app, and are also central to how a user navigates within an app (as with the Back button) or between apps (as with the Recents button). </item>
        <item>A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service, and it continues to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service can handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.</item>
        <item>Content providers can help an application manage access to data stored by itself, stored by other apps, and provide a way to share data with other apps. They encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process. Implementing a content provider has many advantages. </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>


communicator.java

public interface communicator {
    public void respond(int i);
}
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation as well?

Answer (score 0):

//Grid view
main_activity.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

mainactivity.java

package com.example.harish.mylayoutexamples;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class GridActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    GridView gridView;
    static final String[] numbers = new String[] {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
        // Create adapter to set value for grid view
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    /*    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) v).getText()  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText()  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

main_activity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements communicator {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void respond(String i) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentB f2= (FragmentB)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changedata(i);
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple.FragmentA">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple.FragmentB">
    </fragment>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

fragment_A.java

```
package com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    int count=0;
    Button bt;
    communicator comm;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm= (communicator) getActivity();
        bt=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn);
        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         count++;
         comm.respond("The button is clicked "+ count+"   times");
    }
}
```

FRAGMET_A.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple.FragmentA"
    android:background="#99FF00">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="counter"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

FRAGMENT_B.java

```
package com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        txt=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }
    public void changedata(String i)
    {
       txt.setText(i);
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT_B.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple.FragmentB"
    android:background="#FFBB00">
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="haiiii"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

COMMUNICATOR.java

```
package com.example.dhanya.myfragmentcommsimple;
public interface communicator {
    public void respond(String i);
    }
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this code best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and help to ensure it isn't deleted during review.

Answer (score 0):

fragments dynamic loading

Main activity. Java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button firstFragment, secondFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // get the reference of Button's
        firstFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstFragment);
        secondFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondFragment);
        // perform setOnClickListener event on First Button
        firstFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // load First Fragment
                loadFragment(new FirstFragment());
            }
        });
        // perform setOnClickListener event on Second Button
        secondFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // load Second Fragment
                loadFragment(new SecondFragment());
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // create a FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
       // android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        // create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the Fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        // replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
       //fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.firstFragment,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


MAIN_ACTIVTY.XML

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- display two Button's and a FrameLayout to replace the Fragment's  -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/button_background_color"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/button_background_color"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>





FIRST_FRAGMENT.JAVA

package com.abhiandroid.fragmentexample;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    Button firstButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        // get the reference of Button
        firstButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
        // perform setOnClickListener on first Button
        firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // display a message by using a Toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "First Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}


FIRST_FRAGMENT>XML

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abhiandroid.fragmentexample.FirstFragment">
    <!--TextView and Button displayed in First Fragment -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="This is First Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>


SECOND_FRAGMENT>JAVA

package com.abhiandroid.fragmentexample;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    Button secondButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        // get the reference of Button
        secondButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.secondButton);
        // perform setOnClickListener on second Button
        secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // display a message by using a Toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Second Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}


SECOND_FRAGMENT>XML

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abhiandroid.fragmentexample.SecondFragment">
    <!--TextView and Button displayed in Second Fragment -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="This is Second Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.